# Web font not working online. but working locally

Tags: css, html, fonts

I'm trying to work on my website but for some reason the web fonts are not working, even though they work fine on my local machine

please have a look on my css codes. its up on github.

**css style code**
https://github.com/AlexFTWW/alexftww/blob/gh-pages/css/style.css

**website**
https://alexftww.github.io/alexftww/

and it should look like this. much thinner
http: //prntscr.com/45krlw

Comment: Why don't you post the code here or jsFiddle or pastebin? We don't want to be going through your whole project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on chrome console

```
[blocked] The page at 'https://alexftww.github.io/alexftww/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100italic,300,300italic,400,400italic': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

just change the url to:

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100italic,300,300italic,400,400italic

note: the website use a secure protocol (https) , the external resources wold be loaded using https protocol